# Titanum Alloy 3.2 app template does not have app.js file

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm running Titanium 3.2.0 and I've created a new Mobile App project with the Alloy template... the thing is the file app.js that all tutorials refer to isn't found. The structure I have include alloy.js under /app and it includes index.js under /app/controllers

Is this a change in 3.2? Where can I find documentation around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed the way Alloy works, there is no app.js.

In **alloy.js** you can, as the comment of this file suggests, *do any initialization for your app or create any global variables/functions that you'd like to make available throughout your app.*

You can compare **index.js** to app.js, it is the entry point to your application (after alloy.js). You can set up your tabGroups or navigationWindows here, the corresponding view is **index.xml** and the styles are **index.tss**.

To learn more about the structure of Alloy projects, I would recommend Appcelerators [Alloy Framwork docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework).

Sample applications for Alloy can be found [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/test/apps).

Comment: Awesome thanks! What's strange is that even the 3.1 material on Lynda.com makes reference to App.js in Alloy templates.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can still use the classic Titanium approach, you do not necessarily have to use Alloy. If you create a New Project->Titanium->Mobile App project, you can choose here if you want to use Alloy or Classic "style", so if you want to follow a course based on classic, choose this template. One of the advantages of Alloy is that you have your code separated and organized in (models), controllers, views and styles. This allows for much cleaner code and maintainability. In the end, alloy projects are compiled to classic projects anyway ;)

Comment: This was a huge help. I'm following a Lynda.com course on Titanium, and it seems to be pretty outdated. It sucked that I got lost in one of the first videos because I couldn't find app.js. Even some comments in the new ti project talk about an app.js, so I thought I had screwed up the installation or something. Thanks for the insight.